# Convert Date String to Day in Scala

Tags: scala, date, simpledateformat

I have a Date String

`val ts = "2020-02-05 15:12:01-0800"`

I need to get the value till of last day of week. i.e **2020-02-08**

This is what I did till now using SimpleDateFormat

```
val DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"
val ts = "2020-02-05 15:12:01-0800"
val date = df.parse(ts)

val Cal =Calendar.getInstance()
Cal.set (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY)
Cal.setTime(date)

val LastDayOfWeek=DATE_FORMAT.format (Cal.getTime ())
```

However it is returning "2020-02-05 15:12:01-0800"

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleDate is pretty old and outdated. Here's a solution with the current `java.time.LocalDate` library.

```
import java.time.{LocalDate,DayOfWeek}

val ts = "2020-02-05 15:12:01-0800"
val ld = LocalDate.parse(ts take 10)
val saturday = ld.plusDays(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY.getValue()
                           - ld.getDayOfWeek().getValue())
//saturday: java.time.LocalDate = 2020-02-08
```

Note that if the `ts` date is a Sunday then `saturday` will be the day before.

Comment: Basically a fine answer (+1). As a matter of taste I’d use a `DateTimeFormatter`, for example `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXX")`. And I’d definitely leave to the library to find Saturday: `ld.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY))`. Also if today is Sunday, you would be adding 6 - 7 days, that is, subtracting 1 day.

Comment: This is great. Thanks a lot. Let me try and will update you if it worked. Really appreciated

Comment: I need to format the date to Hourly etc and I am not able to do this. Here is what I tried: ```val parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(ts, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"))```. But this is by default creating output to this format -- 2020-02-05

Comment: Thanks. I just did that. :)